# Getting type of a type parameter constrained class in C# 3.5

Tags: c#, generics, types

I'm trying to get the type of a custom class to which I don't have access to editing and it has a  parameter type constraint on its declaration. Just like this:

```
public class GenericItemCollection<T> where T : System.IEquatable<T>
{
    public GenericItemCollection();
    public GenericItemCollection(string json);

    public int Count { get; }
    public List<T> Created { get; }
    public List<T> Current { get; }
    public List<T> Deleted { get; }
    public List<T> Original { get; }
    public List<T> Updated { get; }

    public void AcceptChanges();
    public void AddItem(T item);
    public void BindItem(T item);
    public void DeleteItem(T item);
    public void UpdateItem(T item);
}
```

}

So what I want is the type GenericItemCollection when T is actually something. Ie:

```
private void MyMethod<T>(GenericItemCollection<T> genericList){
    Type listType = typeof(GenericItemCollection<typeof(T)>);
    //...
}
```

which will be called as such:

```
MyMethod<Foo>(fooGenericList);
MyMethod<Bar>(barGenericList);
```

In that case, I want listType to be

```
GenericItemCollection<Foo>
```

and

```
GenericItemCollection<Bar>
```

I know typeof(T) won't exist before runtime but it should return a Type regardless but VS just says "Type expected" on

```
GenericItemCollection<typeof(T)>
```

I'm not all that proficient using Generics, so I'm obviously missing something and I'd like you guys to point out what that is. Many thanks.

Comment: Why not provide a `base class` that both `Foo` and `Bar` inherits from and add that as the constraint in your generic?

Comment: do you want to **restrict** the types ?

Comment: III Not a bad idea, but I seem to have found what I wanted with MakeGenericType. I'll just run some more tests and answer my own question if anyone else does before it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, whatever constraint is applied to the generic type parameter of `GenericItemCollection` must also be applied to the generic type parameter of `MyMethod`

```
private void MyMethod<T>(GenericItemCollection<T> genericList) where T: IEquatable<T>
```

Then, just replace `typeof(T)` with `T`

```
Type listType = typeof(GenericItemCollection<T>);
```

Comment: First thing I tried friend. A got a nice "There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.IEquatable<T>'" error.

Comment: @S.O. You got that error *before* adding the constraint, right?

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked the fact that I must add the constraint to the method declaration.

Comment: I deleted my post but I'm attaching the link to your fiddle here so it doesn't go to waste: dotnetfiddle.net/22JMHR